# How to update Julia version in s specific environment

Tags: julia

When I open a new terminal and run julia in versioninfo(), I see Julia version 1.10.0.
After opening my working environment and running versioninfo(), I see Julia version 1.9.2
The same version is in Manifest.toml. When I manually change it, it later reverts to an earlier version.

What should I do to update the Julia version in this environment?

Comment: Which operating system? E.g. on Mac it can be installed in */Applications/* and in */usr/local/...* etc. What "working environment"? Is it linked to another installation? Easiest is to remove the old installation and link the new one.

Comment: Linux. 
it is a dev environment